# Binding Django Form Element to AngularJS ng-model

Tags: django, angularjs

Normally, when I use Django's Form API to display model form, I will pass the `form` object to the template via `django.template.Context` and render its fields using Django's templating language:

```
<form role="form" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}           
    {{ form.non_field_errors }}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="id_content">Content</label>
        {{ form.content }}
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

The `form.content` will be rendered as

```
<textarea id="id_content" rows="10" cols="40" name="content" style="margin: 2px; width: 339px; height: 164px;"></textarea>
```

But now I want to use it with `AngularJS`, i.e. binding the input field to an ng-model

```
<textarea ng-model="content" id="id_content" rows="10" cols="40" name="content" style="margin: 2px; width: 339px; height: 164px;"></textarea>
```

Is there anyway to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to override form init method and update widget attributes:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # fields..

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['content'].widget.attrs.update({'ng-model': 'content'})
```

Comment: Thanks. But I've settled for custom filter. I'll post my code later for your review. With filter there is no need to override form init every time.

Comment: @LimH. Sure, there're probably few more ways to do it, another one can be to use [this mixin](http://django-angular.readthedocs.org/en/latest/angular-model-form.html#integrate-a-django-form-with-an-angularjs-model) from django-angular.